# Store different versions of images into different locations with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I was wondering is it possible to store different image versions into different locations.

Let's say I have some private Carrierwave folder defined like this:

```
def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/private/uploads/"
end
```

And a couple of versions of uploaded images:

```
version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
end

version :large do
    process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
  end

version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
end
```

I would like to store uploaded image, medium version and large version of that image in defined `store_path` but would like to have thumb version available to users stored in public folder, for example inside that default public folder:

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

How can I accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to override `store_dir` inside the `version` block. So for your example,

```
version :medium do
  process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
end

version :large do
  process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
end

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In old version of carrierwave I have used the version_name, I am not sure if it works now

```
def store_dir
  if version_name != 'thumb'
    # path for other versions
  else
    # path for thumb version
  end
end
```